# Running lua_pcall asynchronously

Tags: c, asynchronous, lua, task

I'm having a C application and I'm integrating LUA as a scripting language in it, Embedding LUA went fine with no problems.

Currently I want to know if it's possible to run 2 or 3 different scripts at the same time from my C application, I have noticed that  lua_pcall is running synchronously (so it doesn't return until it finishes the complete execution of the script.

Is there any way to run multiple scripts at the same time, or at least let lua_pcall run asynchronously. I don't want a solution in the script itself, because I have no control on the scripts that will run (Customer will be writing the scripts for configuration and I don't want to tell him you have to do so, and so, and so inside your script to handle the synchronization.

Comment: lua is single threaded. If you want multiple threads you need to arrange for that yourself with multiple lua states. There are various libraries around that let you do this from the lua side. Doing this from the C side should involve little more work than running multiple threads yourself each with a lua state of their own.

Comment: @EtanReisner, running two different threads on C "side"  and starting separate Lua state on each of them doesn't sound too difficult neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eran says, you can run a fresh lua_State (one created from newthread) in a seperate system thread quite easily.

The only thing you really need to to on top of this is some basic locking (implement lua_lock/lua_unlock/init/shutdown) so that global state elements (_G, Registry, some internals) are not accessed from multiple threads.